# Can I use a python regex for letters, dashes and underscores?

Tags: python, regex, django, google-app-engine, operator-precedence

I want to handle geographic names i.e /new_york or /new-york etc
and since new-york is django-slugify for New york then maybe I should use the slugifed names even if names with underscores look better since I may want to automate the URL creation via an algorithm such as django slugify. A guess is that `([A-Za-z]+)` or simply `([\w-]+)` can work but to be safe I ask you which regex is best choice in this case. 
I've already got a regex that handles number connecting numbers to a class:

`('/([0-9]*)',ById)`#fetches and displays an entity by id

Now I want another regex to match names e.g. new_york so that a request for
/new_york gets handled by the appropriate handler. Basically the negation of the regex above would or any combination letters+underscore and maybe a dash - since the names are geographical and It seems I could use this regex but I believe it works only because of precedence it that it just takes everything:

`('/(.*)', ByName)`#Handle for instance /new_york entities, /sao_paulo entities etc by custom mapping for my relevant places.

Since I have other handlers and I don't want conflicting regexes and I have other request handlers, could you recommend how to formulate the regex?

How does it work when an expression suits 2 regexes? Which has higher precedence? Can you tell me more how I should learn to write regexes and possible implementations for the geographical datastore - as entities or instance variables and special problems such as geographic locations that have different names in different languages e.g. Germany in german is called Deutschland so I also want to apply translations that I can do with gettext / djang.po files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first match wins.

usually your URLs will differ in other parts of the path.  for example you might have

```
/cities/(?P<city>[^/]+)
/users/(?P<user>[^/]+)
```

and in many cases [^/]+ is a good regex because it will match anything except /, which you would normally avoid because it is used to separate path elements.

i don't think it's a good idea to separate URLs based solely on characters (in your case, letters or digits), but if you want to do that, use `[-A-Za-z_]+` (note that the "-" goes at the start of the [], or it needs a backslash).

avoid `\w` because that can also match digits.  unless you want to go really crazy and send digits only to one handler and letters+digits elsewhere, in which case use:

```
/(?P<id>\d+)
/(?P<city>[-\w]+)
```

in that order.

Comment: Thanks andrew I'm still trying to learn how to use regexes properly. One URL will look like /view/323 where the digit part is dynamic and represents the entity id while at the same time allowing requests per geography to be handled e.g. /new_york/manhattan. For now I just set 3 regexes where 1 matches /new_york and one matches /new_york/manhattan while still not conflicting with the single entity view.